# Convert OL3 Geometry EPSG

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm catching the creation of a shape on 'drawend' and writing out the geometry of that shape...

The problem id that I need to convert this geometry from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326

I've used ol.proj.transform to do this before but I can't seem to figure out how to get this function to work in this particular instance...

The code I'm working with looks like this...

```
 draw.on('drawend', function (e) {

                        if (webMapValues.drawType == 'Polygon') {                          

                            var latLonFeature = ol.proj.transform(e, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
                            var format = new ol.format.WKT();
                            var wktfeaturegeom = format.writeGeometry(e.feature.getGeometry());
```

...So the preferred out come would be to have wktfeaturegeom in EPSG:4326

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will transform the result of a drawend event:

```
e.feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
```

Comment: Works like a charm...apparently I'm making this too hard on myself :)